# Registering user controls in cascading web.config files

Tags: asp.net, webforms, user-controls, web-config

I have a web.config file in the root folder of my ASP.NET Web Application that registers all user controls in my project.

> ~/web.config
>
> ~/Controls/MyReusableControl.ascx
>
> ~/Non/Reusable/Controls/AnotherControl.ascx
>
> ~/Non/Reusable/Even/More/Specific/Controls/MyThirdControl.ascx

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="uc" tagName="MyReusableControl" src="~/Controls/MyReusableControl.ascx" />
            <add tagPrefix="uc" tagName="AnotherControl" src="~/Non/Reusable/Controls/AnotherControl.ascx" />
            <add tagPrefix="uc" tagName="MyThirdControl" src="~/Non/Reusable/Even/More/Specific/Controls/MyThirdControl.ascx" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Registering every control in the root web.config file seems like a bad idea. Most of my controls are designed specifically for a single page or a group of related pages.

I'd like to register my non-reusable controls in a web.config file that is logically closer to the page where the controls are actually used.

---

> ~/Controls/MyControl.ascx
>
> ~/web.config

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="uc" tagName="MyReusableControl" src="~/Controls/MyReusableControl.ascx" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

---

> ~/Non/Reusable/Controls/AnotherControl.ascx
>
> ~/Non/Reusable/web.config

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="uc" tagName="AnotherControl" src="~/Non/Reusable/Controls/AnotherControl.ascx" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

---

> ~/Non/Reusable/Even/More/Specific/Controls/MyThirdControl.ascx
>
> ~/Non/Reusable/Even/More/Specific/web.config

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="uc" tagName="MyThirdControl" src="~/Non/Reusable/Even/More/Specific/Controls/MyThirdControl.ascx" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

---

Am I allowed to do that? I tried simply moving the relevant parts of the configuration to the new web.config files, but that seems to break the web forms designer for pages that reference the non-reusable controls.

> Element 'AnotherControl' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.

Obviously, my web.config files are all there. What's interesting is that my project *does* compile and my web pages *do* show my user controls. It's just Visual Studio designers that crash with the above error.

Comment: Any reason you have opted out of just registering the UserControls directly on the pages that use them?

Comment: I read about it on Phil Haack's blog (http://haacked.com/archive/2006/11/14/register_custom_controls_in_web.config.aspx/). My goal was to not have to register the same user control over and over again for every page that needs it. I just realized that what I'm trying to do is silly because my non-reusable controls won't be registered on more than a few pages anyway.

Comment: Still, this seems like a bug in the webforms designer, considering that my compiled website works as expected.